# Apply jquery formatting to ajax output

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using a `jquery` carousel to display some images in a dynamically populated list.  When the page is first opened it looks great but once the `ajax` replaces the contents of the div containing carousel content all of the formatting etc is lost.

I understand that this is because the `ajax` content is newly created and didn't exist when the carousel script did it job but I'm not sure how I can get it to apply the formatting to the new content?

This is the ajax call displaying the newly created data

```
$(function(){
    var audit_id = $('#auditID').val();
    var btnUpload=$('#upload');
    var status=$('#status');
    new AjaxUpload(btnUpload, {
        action: '../ajax/upload_standard_ajax.php?audit_id='+audit_id,
        name: 'uploadfile',
        onSubmit: function(file, ext){
             if (! (ext && /^(jpg|JPG)$/.test(ext))){ 
                status.text('Only jpg files are allowed');
                return false;
            }
                status.text('Uploading...');
        },
            onComplete: function(response){
                status.text('');
                //if(response==="success"){
                  $.ajax({
                      url: 'ajax/create_audit_standard_carosel.php',
                      type:'POST',
                      data: 'audit_id='+audit_id,
                     success: function(response){
                    $('#selected_standards').html(response);
                    }, // End of success function of ajax form
                error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
               alert(thrownError);
            }
         }); // End of ajax call
        }
    }); 
});
```

The html used to trigger the ajax call

```
<a href="#" class="upload_stuff ipad_hide">
   <div id="upload">
     <span class="upload_btn">&nbsp;</span>
   </div>
</a>
<span id="status" ></span>
```

The ajax response

```
$output .='<ul id="standards_list" class="touchcarousel-container">';
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){          
      $output .='<li class="touchcarousel-item">';
      $output .='<img src="'.$row['imageLocation'].'" width="200" >';
      $output .='</li>';               
    }
$output .='</ul>';
```

I've tried it just having it all on one line and I've also tried leaving the `ul` intact on the original page and just outputing the `li` element.  I've also tried using `json` and just `echo` for the resonse

I can apply the formatting by refreshing the screen but it kind of defeats the object of using ajax

Comment: What are you getting back in your `response`?  You may have to style the elements in your response by splitting them up as JSON(?) objects then style them after you've replaced your `.html()` content.

Comment: The elements are just list, I'll add it to the question

Comment: you need to reinitialize the carousel, some libraries provide like an `update`/`refresh` etc type functions to update to new content, or other functions to provide new content for the carousel. Check the docs of the particular library you are using to see if they provide such functions. Also provide the name of the carousel library you are using, maybe someone will know it and be able to help better.

Comment: @PatrickEvans - indirectly you helped me solve my problem, I put the section of code used to initialise the carrousel in the success section of the ajax call.  I have spent 2 days working on this and it was that simple, thanks!  If you add an answer I will accept it

Answer (score 0):

My reputation is too low so I can't comment, but first, what do you mean by formatting? Do you mean CSS styles? It would help if you showed the markup for the element that is represented by #selected_standards.

If you mean "CSS formatting", I suspect that when you do:

```
$("#selected_standards").html(response);
```

you are overwriting the contents of #selected_standards and thus losing the CSS formatting.

Grab the current value of the classes assigned to #selected_standards (or its children, depends on your document structure) and then re-attach those classes to the elements that had them before.

You can do something like

```
var previousClasses = $("#selected_standards").attr("class");
// your existing code to insert HTML
$("#selected_standards").attr("class", previousClasses);
```

Comment: I'm afraid I thought of that but there was too much, the script not only formats but makes it into a draggable slider etc